# Razor page return value when !ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm try to fire validation of input field, but what i need to return?

This is my CSHTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="wExternal_ID.ExternalKey"></label>
    <input asp-for="wExternal_ID.ExternalKey" id="_ExternalKey" name="ExternalKEY" class="form-control" required/>
    <span asp-validation-for="wExternal_ID.ExternalKey" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

This is my code:

```
[BindProperty]
public ExternalID wExternal_ID { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnPostSaveExternalKEY(string GUID)
    {
        try
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            TryValidateModel(wExternal_ID);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ...
                return new OkResult();
            }
            else
            {
                return ---WHAT TO ENABLE VALIDATION??---
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return  ...;
        }
    }
```

And my model class:

```
public class Customer_ExternalID
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ExternalKey { get; set; }
}
```

I have try to return Page() but i've error Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source').

Comment: Does the get method for the current page take any parameters?

Comment: Any data that you prepare for the OnGet method also needs to be prepared prior to calling return Page();

Comment: @pcalkins, yes the page take the id of customer as parameter.

Comment: @MikeBrind, can you explane me how can i prepare?

Comment: You prepare the data in the same way as you did in the `OnGet` method.

Comment: the error you are getting is because the id is null... probably because of ModelState.Cear()?

Comment: No, ModelState.Clear() is not the problem; i've found that i have a nested class not initialized. Now return Page() doesn't give error but modal popup disappared.